# bash add string from variable using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I need to edit a files using shell script (sed),
I can't seem to get it to work when I use "space" inside my string.

This is the bash script:

```
##Edit instancegroup files with relevant cluster
CLUSTER_NAME=clusters.dev10.k8s.local
oldcluster="kops.k8s.io/cluster:"
newcluster="kops.k8s.io/cluster: ${CLUSTER_NAME}"
sed -i 's@'${oldcluster}'@'${newcluster}'@g' myfile
```

This is ***myfile***:

```
apiVersion: kops/v1alpha2
kind: InstanceGroup
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-01-03T10:45:43Z
  labels:
    kops.k8s.io/cluster:
```

And this is the error I get:

```
administrator@JenkisSrv01:~/awscluster/instancegroup$ ./try.sh
sed: -e expression #1, char 43: unterminated `s' command
```

When I removing the space from line 4, it is working well:

```
newcluster="kops.k8s.io/cluster:${CLUSTER_NAME}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unquoted space separates parameters. Quote the variable:

```
sed -i 's@'"${oldcluster}"'@'"${newcluster}"'@g' myfile
```

or more readably

```
sed -i "s@$oldcluster@$newcluster@g" myfile
```

Note that `.` has a special meaning in regexes, so `kops.k8s.io/cluster:` matches e.g. `kopsXk8sXio/cluster:`. You need to backslash the dots to force the literal meaning.

Answer (score 0):

add double quotes around variables

```
sed -i 's@'"${oldcluster}"'@'"${newcluster}"'@g' myfile
```